# How to use JQuery to add different content to elements with same class respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I have used django to create a model ***company*** with attributes ***name*** and ***address***, and display only the names of all companies in query-set. What I want jquery to do is to display corresponding address when click the name (via ajax).

Below are my code. So ajax request is being processed correctly and is able to display corresponding address, but all `<ul class="address_result">` displayed the same thing each time, which makes sense since I am adding `html(data)` to the class and thus all of its element. Is there a way to display address respectively to each name within each `<div class="name_address">`, maybe add id? Thanks in advance!

*JQuery:*

```
$(function(){
    $('.name').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/#link to backend get_address function/",
            data:{
                'name': $(this).html(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: get_address_success,
            datatype:'html'
        });
    });

});

function get_address_success(data, textStatus,jqXHR){
    $('.address_result').html(data);
}
```

*html:*

```
{% for obj in list %}
<div class="name_address">
    <h4 class="name">{{ obj.name }}</h4>
    <ul class="address_result"></ul>
</div>
{% endfor%}
```

*get_address function in django:*

```
def get_address(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    company_name = request.POST.get('name','')
else:
    company name = ''
companies = company.objects.filter(name=company_name) #Name different companies can have the same name in this case
context = {
    'companies':companies
}
return render_to_response('ajax_get_address.html', context) #ajax_get_address.html just returns all companies' addresses that correspond to the name
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.name').on('click', function(){
        var Name=$(this).html();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/#link to backend get_address function/",
            data:{
                'name': Name,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: get_address_success,
            datatype:'html'
        });
        function get_address_success(data, textStatus,jqXHR)
        {
            $("#"+Name).html(data);
        }
    });

});




{% for obj in list %}
<div>
    <h4 class="name">{{ obj.name }}</h4>
    <ul class="address_result" id="{{obj.name}}"></ul>
</div>
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: Are there more than one `.address_result` divs in your page?

Comment: Yes, there is a for loop in html that iterates through the queryset and display all company names, each time a <div class="name_address"> is created.

Comment: how does the get_address function look like?

Comment: added in the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this to your html generation

```
<div id="{{ obj.name }}" class="name_address">
```

And then select the individual `address_result` by using that ID as part of the response you send from your backend. A json like this around your exist
ing data would do

```
{"name" : "name_of_block_to_change",
 "content" : data}
```

And your success callback can do this

```
function get_address_success(data, textStatus,jqXHR){
     var id = data["name"];
     $('#'+id+' .address_result').html(data["content"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tried your way of assign id with {{ obj.name }} to `<ul class="address_result" id="{{ obj.name }}">` , but directly added `html(data)` to element with id= `'#'+$(this).html()` ,instead of using json.  (as in solution added in description) Is there any disadvantage of this compared to using json?

Comment: in my case, its not likely because I used `list = company.objects.values('name').annotate(Count("addresses"))` in another django function, so that in the for loop, `list` is a query with all **distinct** names.

Comment: Nope, I think that is a better solution, if it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using attributes for the id, send id to ajax, get the address and add it to the next  address_result ul:

```
{% for obj in list %}
<div class="name_address">
    <h4 class="name" data-id="{{obj.id}}">{{ obj.name }}</h4>
    <ul class="address_result"></ul>
</div>
{% endfor%}
```

js:

```
$(function(){
    $('.name').on('click', function(){
        var el = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/#link to backend get_address function/",
            data:{
                'name': el.html(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                'id':el.attr('data-id');
            },
            success: get_address_success,
            datatype:'html'
        });
    });

});

function get_address_success(data, textStatus,jqXHR){
    $(el).next('.address_result').html(data);
}
```

get_address function:

```
def get_address(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    company_name = request.POST.get('name','')
    company_id = request.POST.get('id','')
else:
    company name = ''
companies = company.objects.filter(name=company_name).filter(id=company_id) 
context = {
    'companies':companies
}
return render_to_response('ajax_get_address.html', context) #ajax_get_address.html just returns all companies' addresses that correspond to the name & id
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, appreciate it!